# Nondegenerate Basic Feasible Solution for network flow problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

I am reading the network simplex algorithm of [Bertsimas' Introduction to Linear Optimization](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Linear_Optimization.html?id=GAFsQgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description). The graph below shows a degenerate basic feasible solution because the flow from node $6$ to node $7$ is $0$. I am wondering if there is anyway to find a non-degenerate Basic Feasible Solution (BFS). In addition, is there anyway to find all non-degenerate BFS's?

[image: Network Flow]

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry I meant basic feasible solution.

Comment: Since nothing can leave node $7$, any feasible solution will have flow $0$ in both arcs $5$ to $7$ and $6$ to $7$.  But a basis must include at least one of the arcs entering $7$.